# String interpolation: f or s

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I wonder, is there any difference between these two:

```
val a = 123
println(f"hello1 $a") // 1                         
println(s"hello1 $a") // 2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html), `f` interpolation is typesafe. Also, it allows to add formatting right after the parameter, which `s` interpolation doesn't support.

Answer (score 10):

The `s` interpolator allows you to plug in variables or expressions, while the `f` interpolator allows you to use formatting commands, *à la* C `printf`.

Note that contrary to C `printf` or Java `String.format`, the `f` interpolator will typecheck the arguments for you. [This link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) has more information.

Comment: expressions are supported by `f` too